# SBT using sbt-native-packager how to create different build files?

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play 2.3 Application, following the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist) I can build a debian package, the problem comes when I want to build things like this:

I have different configurations for `dev, qa and prod`, and I want to build to 4 different packages, one that contains the code and the others that contains the configuration. so I will get this 4 packages:

```
app-version.deb [this contains the code]
app-config-dev-version.deb [this contains the dev configuration]
app-config-qa-version.deb [this contains the qa configuration]
app-config-prod-version.deb‏ [this contains the prod configuration]
```

but for installing app-version.deb I will need one of the others as a dependency depending on the machine.

```
machine-dev: app-version.deb and app-config-dev-version.deb
machine-qa:  app-version.deb and app-config-qa-version.deb
and so on ...
```

Comment: Typically with debian packaging you would have your package install with a set of reference configuration, and use tools like [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) or [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) to manage specific environments.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring your application with additional debian packages is not a good idea in my experience. For a play application you have other options that are a lot easier to create and maintain.

## Use multiple .conf files

Play uses the [Typesafe Config Library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). Create a configuration file for each of your environments, e.g.

```
conf/
  reference.conf   # contains default settings
  dev.conf
  qa.conf
  prod.conf
```

Now how to define which one gets packaged? Well there are a few options.

### Package them all and choose at startup time

Package all and choose at startup time which to use:

```
./bin/your-app -Dconfig.resource=conf/prod.conf
```

This is straight forward and works if you have control over how things get started.

### Package them all and choose package time

You can add the start command during build time via `javaOptions in Universal`. You can do this either with a [Command Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338110/can-sbt-execute-compile-testcompile-itcompile-as-a-single-command-say-co) or a [custom task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html)

### Copy and rename specific conf

Basically you choose (for example with a custom task as above) which
configuration to include as `application.conf`.

```
mappings in Universal += {
  val conf = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "reference.conf"
  conf -> "conf/application.conf"
}
```

I recommend against that as you have no idea which package you are using at the moment.

**UPDATE**

### Use submodules

Configurations/Scopes are more complicated and behave sometimes in unexpected ways. The easy alternative is to use submodules.

```
your-app/
  app
  conf
  ..
dev/
qa/
prod/
```

Your `build.sbt` would then contain something like this

```
lazy val app = project
  .in(file("your-app"))
  .enabledPlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
     // your settings
  )

lazy val dev = project
  .in(file("dev"))
  // this one is tricky. 
  // Maybe it works when using the PlayScala Plugin
  .enabledPlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    // if you only use the JavaServerAppPackaging plugin 
    // you will need to specifiy a mainclass
    //mainClass in Compile := Some("")
)

// ... rest the same way
```

In the end you build with `dev/debian:packageBin` for development.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was great the problem is that I do not want to share the configuration files with the packages. And I need how to do that. Can you show me how to do that?. So in your last purpose, I have to build three packages dev, prod, qa, and every package will have only one configuration file?

Comment: Using the 'Use multiple .conf files' method, with my resources/application.conf and resources/prod.conf present. I was able to use the prod.conf with below command.

First, built using sbt universal:pacakageBin
Then executed ./bin/your-app -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf at root of the extracted zip/project folder.